# Converting a sentence into piglatin

Tags: python

So I have a function that takes a sentence and returns in piglatin. The code is as follows:

```
import re
from string import ascii_uppercase

def isvowel(ch):
    vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
    for i in range(len(ch)):
        if ch[i] in vowels:
            return i
    return -1


def format(ch):
    if any(x in ascii_uppercase for x in ch): 
        ch = ch.capitalize()
    m = re.search(r'\W+', ch) 
    if m: 
        ch = ch.replace(m.group(0), '') + m.group(0)
    return ch 


def igpay(astring):
    vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
    words =  astring.split()
    count = 0
    for ch in words:
        vowel = isvowel(ch)
        if vowel == 0:
            astring = astring.replace(ch,(format(ch + "way")))
        else:
            astring = astring.replace(ch,(format(ch[vowel:] + ch[:vowel] + "ay")))
    astring = astring.strip()        
    return astring
```

The output works fine when I input a single word, but when I input a sentence it goes haywire.

Example:
What Im getting:

```
>>>igpay("An apple a day keeps the doctor away")
>>>'Anwawaywayy awaywaypplewawaywayy awayway dawaywayy eepskay ethay octorday       awaywaywawaywayy'
```

What I should get:

```
>>>igpay("An apple a day keeps the doctor away")
>>>'Anway appleway away ayday eepskay ethay octorday awayway'
```

If I input each word separately, I get a correct return. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are modifying the whole sentence in the loop by replacing word endings.

Instead, you should do it for each word in a list, gather words to the list and return them joined by space:

```
def igpay(astring):
    words = astring.split()
    modified_words = []
    for ch in words:
        vowel = isvowel(ch)
        if vowel == 0:
            ch = ch.replace(ch, (format(ch + "way")))
        else:
            ch = ch.replace(ch, (format(ch[vowel:] + ch[:vowel] + "ay")))
        modified_words.append(ch.strip())
    return ' '.join(modified_words)
```

Example usage (exactly what you were looking for):

```
>>> igpay("An apple a day keeps the doctor away")
'Anway appleway away ayday eepskay ethay octorday awayway'
```